# HTML Redirect with Authentication using jsp pages

Tags: javascript, java, html, http, jsp

Basically, I have a jsp page that when loaded will redirect the user to another URL (google.com for example). The problem I'm running into is the URL that the user is being redirected to has it's own authentication, and I'm trying to avoid the user needing to login with different credentials (I dont want to give them my UN & PW)... Is there a method or a way to hard code the username and password in the code so that it is used during the redirect?

This is what I'm doing right now:

```
<html>

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=https://www.google.com/" />
</head>

<body>
    <p>Please Wait...</p>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!
Shawn

Comment: This is the first time I am using this site, so please let me know if I can be more clear, etc. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the redirect is to another page of your site, store user information as you can in the session and use it on another page:
Session training
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp
If you do not want to use PHP, you can send the information using the Get Address method and encode the information with one of the algorithms, but this method is not recommended !!
(I can not write good English)

Comment: It is not to another page in my site. It is outside the original site which is why i used google.com as an example.

Comment: you can send  via get method .
for example : google.com?user=mehdi&pass=051